# Installed Add-on, doesn't appear in export options

Tags: add-on

Basically I've installed an add-on / exporter to blender via preferences, i've downloaded from the zip file and also attempted to unzip and multiselect all the content in the file. It's downloaded however the exporter does not appear in 'Export' options strangely. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What add-on are you trying to install? Have you tried to install it through *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*? Does Blender show any error message?